# Convert int[] to boolean[]

Tags: java, arrays, multiplication

Any clever way to convert an integer array to a boolean array, given the guarantee that the `int[]` only contains `1`s and `0`s?

That is, convert:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

to

```
[false, false, true, false, false, false, true true]
```

Of course, I can loop over the `int[]` but am wondering if there's something more elegant out there? Maybe something like `(new int[]{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}) * true`?

Comment: No there is no elegant way of doing that

Comment: In Java 8 you can use Stream. map

Comment: @codequestioneer there is since Java 8 but the result is a `Boolean[]` not a `boolean[]`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Then I have to say Im sorry. Im not really up to date when it omes to Java 8, since I have to make my projects work on Java 1.6 :P

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a sensible question.

Answer (score 3):

Using Java 8 you can readily convert to a `Boolean[]` with something like

```
Boolean[] bools = Arrays.stream(ints)
        .mapToObj(i -> i == 1)
        .toArray(Boolean[]::new);
```

But there is no neat way to create a `boolean[]`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the streams approach can only arrays of reference type, so the result has to be an array of boxed `Boolean` values.

Here's what I'd do instead:

```
int[] intArray = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 }; // input

boolean[] boolArray = new boolean[intArray.length];
IntStream.range(0, intArray.length).forEach(i -> boolArray[i] = intArray[i] != 0);
```

Yeah, it's side-effecty, but what the heck. This is essentially what `Arrays.setAll(boolean[])` would do if it existed, but it only exists for the usual trio of `int`, `long`, and `double`.

(This requires Java 8.)